# Как загрузить картинку из памяти, зная её полный путь?

Tags: android, файлы

Сохранил картинку на телефоне из приложения. Файловым менеджером нашёл её и удостоверился, что она действительно сохранилась. Далее пытаюсь по её полному пути загрузить её методом **BitmapFactory.decodeFile()** передавая туда полный путь к картинке, путь к картинкам у меня такой, приведу пример из приложения:

`/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.home.page/files/2015218161530.jpg`

Но мне выскакивает **Exception**, что декодирование невозможно, т.к. файл не найден. Что за ерунда?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Второй раз вопрос задаете и опять без кода декодирования. Код приведите хотя бы, как людям узнать, где у вас ошибка без него?

Comment: В третий раз напишу, может с третьего раза дойдет до вас... Выложите код вызова BitmapFactory.decodeFile()

Comment: Metalurgus, может вам не видно, но в вопросе написано, что я пихаю 
/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.home.page/files/2015218161530.jpg
как параметр метода BitmapFactory.decodeFile(), т.е. выглядит это так:
BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolytlyPath()), метод file.getAbsolytlyPath() возвращает ссылку описанную выше.

Я ещё вчера выяснил, что проблема не в декодировании файла, т.к. он декодируется нормально и картинка нормальная, но проблема всё равно есть, т.к. я создаю адаптер для наполнения AdapterViewFlipper, а та уже проблемы и картинки не выводятся, выскакивает та ошибка

Comment: а file.exists() вы проверяли?

Comment: да, проверял, всё в норме